# Error occuer when creating a VM in azure using ansible

Tags: azure, ansible

i am using azure=0.11.1 and also tried in 1.0.1 version and execute it but i getting same error which mention below, playbook is mention below:

*azurevm_yml*

`---
   - local_action:
     module: "azure"
     name: 'vm_ubuntu1'
     role_size: Small
     image: '5112500ae3b842c8b9c604889f8753c3__OpenLogic-CentOS-67-20150815'
     password: "admin12345@"
     location: 'East US 2'
     user: admin
     wait: yes
     subscription_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
     management_cert_path: '/ansible-pbook/xxxx.pem'
     storage_account: 'storageacc01'
     endpoints: '22,8080,80'
     register: azure_vm`

Error:

`root@xxxxx:/ansible-pbook# ansible-playbook azure_vm.yml
ERROR: password is not a legal parameter of an Ansible Play`

Please suggest me...

Answer (score 0):

The correct format for a task is something like this:

```
- local_action: azure
    name='vm_ubuntu1'
    role_size=Small
    image='5112500ae3b842c8b9c604889f8753c3__OpenLogic-CentOS-67-20150815'
    password="admin12345@"
    location='East US 2'
    user=admin
    wait=yes
    subscription_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    management_cert_path='/ansible-pbook/xxxx.pem'
    storage_account='storageacc01'
    endpoints='22,8080,80'
  register: azure_vm
```

All the parameters passed to the module should be in the format of `key=value`, while attributes to the task/action itself (like `register`, `tags`, `ignore_errors`, etc.) are in the format of `attribute: value`

Comment: Error :azureuser@ansiblemaster:/ansible-pbook$ ansible-playbook azure_vm.yml
ERROR: register is not a legal parameter of an Ansible Play

Comment: Make sure you have your indentation, etc. all correct.  register is indeed a legal parameter. See the [ansible documentation on registering variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables) for a working example..

Comment: I agree with you, but it's showing error and also tried many times, does azure module is flexible with ansible?